# create 'alist' without using 'square bracket delimiters' [ and ] in python code

Tags: python-3.x

I am a newbie to python and learning it from a book, as suggested in this forum by one of the developers. I am trying to create the following list

```
alist == ['47c', ['47d','47e'], '47f']
```

Usually, we do this with the square brackets [ ] to create a list. Is there a way to create 'alist' without using 'square bracket delimiters'  [ and ] in my code?

Thanks in advance for help!

```
# I know of following way and few other methods but they all use [ and ]

alist = ['47c', '47f']
blist = ['47d','47e']

alist.insert(1,blist)
```

Comment: @paxdiablo: It needs to be done this way. As is well-stated in question, I am new so I want to learn this way as well. I won't ask questions if it comes to my keyboard keys. Please be considerate from next time. Thanks!

Comment: Sachin, I'm not *trying* to be inconsiderate, it's just that no Python developer in their right mind would even *consider* creating a list without `[ ]`. In other words, if you're learning Python, learn it well. You can create lists without square brackets but your code will be hideous. Someone proclaiming to be a Python developer and bringing code like that to an interview would be quickly shown the door.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Agree with you. I believe you misunderstood the context. I will never create list this way normally but it was specifically asked to be done this way in one of the programming code interviews. I found it perplexing and hence posted it here to get advice from experts whether it can be done this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can create list without using square brackets.

To do so, create a `list` using the `list()` constructor and then `append` item to it.

```
aList = list()
aList.append('47c')
innerList = list()
innerList.append('47d')
innerList.append('47e')
aList.append(innerList)
aList.append('47f')
print(aList)
```

Output:

```
['47c', ['47d', '47e'], '47f']
```

**Explanation:**

The `list()` constructor returns a mutable sequence list of elements.

- If no parameters are passed, it creates an empty list.
- If iterable is passed as parameter, it creates a list of elements in the iterable.

**Reference:**

- [List tutorial in programiz site](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/list)

Comment: Thanks, @arsho for the kind and prompt help!